# Java dynamically load a class from a jar

Tags: java, maven, dynamic, jar, classloader

On my project, I have a jar dependency that loads a class dynamically. 
The class that must be loaded is specified on an environment variable.

On project level I created a new class which I want now to load from inside the jar. However, when running a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException is thrown.

The code is loading classes correctly when they are inside the jar file.

How can I load a class which is defined on project level from a jar which comes as dependency to that project?

The code I am using on the JAR file to load a class:

```
    String className = System.getProperty("CLASS_TO_LOAD");
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    Constructor<?> constructor;
    constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
    return (AbstractClassObject) constructor.newInstance(myString);
```

I want to load the class with the name specified as a property on my project.

Thanks,

Comment: Show us some code what you are doing.

Comment: There's not enough detail in this question to answer it.  We can't even tell if you ever added the new class to the .jar file.

Comment: Already updated the questions. Hope it is now perceptible.
Thanks in advance